# Writing SQL Query to create spatial view?

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, sql-view

I use this sql query to draw a rectangle from a point layer (overview):

```
create or replace view view_test as
select name, width, height, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (('
 ||ST_X(geom)-(width * (scale * 0.1))/2||' '||ST_Y(geom)-(height*(scale*0.1))/2||','
 ||ST_X(geom)-(width * (scale * 0.1))/2||' '||ST_Y(geom)+(height*(scale*0.1))/2||','
 ||ST_X(geom)+(width * (scale * 0.1))/2||' '||ST_Y(geom)+(height*(scale*0.1))/2||','
 ||ST_X(geom)+(width * (scale * 0.1))/2||' '||ST_Y(geom)-(height*(scale*0.1))/2||','
 ||ST_X(geom)-(width * (scale * 0.1))/2||' '||ST_Y(geom)-(height*(scale*0.1))/2||'))'),32632) as geom
from overview;
```

But QGIS isn't loading the results:

```
2017-07-14T21:38:12 1   dbname='XXXX' host=XX.XX.XXX.XXX port=5432 user='postgres' sslmode=disable key='width' table="public"."view_test" (geom) sql= is an invalid layer - not loaded
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: forgot to include scale in the select clause? does that have an effect?

Comment: right, scale was missing! Now I got the error, that there is no primary key defined. How do I solve that?

Comment: If you do not have a unique field in the table, you must define a field with a SQL subquery 

(SELECT row_number() over () AS _uid_, * from  overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [QGIS wiki](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiQGIS):

> When you don't have a unique id for each row you want to display, you
>   can create on on the fly using the SQL windows to load your
>   geometries. Simply add in the select : SELECT row_number() OVER( ORDER
>   BY field1,field2 ) AS id_qgis , and select id_qgis as the id column in
>   the QGIS list. It is necessary to specify the Order By clause to
>   ensure the same ID is always assigned to the same row, for every
>   query, regardless of the usage of fields and joins that do affect the
>   row order in the result set.